# how can i get the last item in the array

Tags: postgresql

I have jsonb array like this,

`"[{""year"": 2020, ""month"": 8, ""visitor"": 1}, {""year"": 2020, ""month"": 12, ""visitor"": 1}, {""year"": 2021, ""month"": 9, ""visitor"": 1}, {""year"": 2021, ""month"": 11, ""visitor"": 1}, {""year"": 2022, ""month"": 1, ""visitor"": 2}]"`

**Thats my query**

`SELECT to_json(t."MonthlyVisitors")->>-1 as visitor FROM   "Table" t Where "Url"='asd'`

**Query Result**
`"{""year"": 2022, ""month"": 1, ""visitor"": 2}"`

but the answer i want just the last item;2

Comment: Your sample data looks strange. If it's **really** stored like that, then you do not have an array, but a single JSON string - essentially the same as `"foo"`

Comment: I also don't understand why you use `to_json` if the column is defined as `jsonb`. If that is really a `jsonb` column, it sounds as if you just want `t."MonthlyVisitors" -> -1 ->> 'visitor'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `jsonb_array_length`:

```
WITH jsontable(j) AS (
   SELECT JSONB '[{"year": 2020, "month": 8, "visitor": 1},
                  {"year": 2020, "month": 12, "visitor": 1},
                  {"year": 2021, "month": 9, "visitor": 1},
                  {"year": 2021, "month": 11, "visitor": 1},
                  {"year": 2022, "month": 1, "visitor": 2}]'
)
SELECT j -> (jsonb_array_length(j) - 1)
FROM jsontable;

                 ?column?                 
══════════════════════════════════════════
 {"year": 2022, "month": 1, "visitor": 2}
(1 row)
```

Even more efficient is to use the array index -1 (hats off to a_horse_with_no_name):

```
WITH jsontable(j) AS (...)
SELECT j -> -1
FROM jsontable;
```

Comment: `j -> -1` works just fine.